# Find Internal Hosting Server from Website IP

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ip

There is a website hosted on a server on our network, and I'm trying to find where exactly this has been installed.

Using the IP is there anyway that I can resolve this to a machine name on our network?  I've tried pining the IP but don't get anything useful back.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the machine/computer name:

```
PING -a xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
```